# Tastypie Attributes & Related Names, Empty Attribute Error

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm getting this error:

```
The object '' has an empty attribute 'posts' and doesn't allow a default or null value.
```

I'm trying to get the number of 'votes' on a post and return it in my models.py:

```
class UserPost(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='posts')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def get_votes(self):
        return Vote.objects.filter(object_id = self.id)
```

Here's my resource:

```
class ViewPostResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource,'user',full=True)
    votes=  fields.CharField(attribute='posts__get_votes')
    class Meta:
        queryset = UserPost.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'posts'

        authorization = Authorization()
        filtering = {
            'id' : ALL,
            }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `attribute` value that you have defined isn't proper.
You can achieve what you want in a few ways.

Define a `dehydrate` method:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    bundle.data['custom_field'] = bundle.obj.get_votes()
    return bundle
```

Or set the `get_votes` as property and define the field in resource like so (I recommend this one as it is the most clear):

```
votes = fields.CharField(attribute='get_votes', readonly=True, null=True)
```

Or define it this way:

```
votes = fields.CharField(readonly=True, null=True)
```

And in the resources define the dehydrate_votes method like so:

```
def dehydrate_votes(self, bundle):
    return bundle.obj.get_votes()
```

Comment: Your second solution worked, though I'm a bit curious- how does my resources.py know that get_votes is referring to a method in my models.py? Is that just how Tastypie does it?

Comment: If you use the ModelResources from tastypie the `attribute` reffers to the Model's attribute. To be precise it is done in the process of field dehydration, here: 
https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/fields.py#L102